# Unable to Create New Project through Custom Cordova Project Template in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, project-template

I have Created Project Template for The Cordova App in Visual Studio 2015.When i am Creating new Project through this Template , Instead of loading Files It is showing empty Solution Explorer.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Cordova projects do not work with the export as template wizard from Visual Studio. I'm sorry for any inconvenience this has caused you.

(Disclosure: I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova in Visual Studio)